# What does @SCORE(1) mean in JUNIT?

Tags: java, junit

Some legacy code has @SCORE(1) on top of a JUNIT test case and I'm not sure what it means and both Google and the API aren't turning much up

Comment: Chances are it's not a Junit annotation. Any decent IDE will tell you what package that annotation comes from, which should help you narrow your search down.

Comment: May be this junit class has some import which will give you hint what this `Score(1)` is all about?